# assining variables in a function with exec, python

Tags: python, variables, scope, exec

my problem is, that i assign a variable and want to use it later:

```
name_list = ["a", "b","c"]


for x in range (len(name_list) -1):
    exec (name_list[x] + str (x) + "= 0" ) 
    
    print ( name_list[x] + str (x) )
```

Output:

```
a0
b1
```

If i use :

```
print (a0)
```

outside the function, the code analysis will throw an error, because the variable is not assigned yet, but the output is: 0

Answer (score 0):

If you run `exec` inside a function, you should use `global` keyword to get variable visible outside the function.
Like this:

```py
def test(a):
    exec(f"global {a}0; {a}0 = 123")

test('f')

print(f0)

output: 123
```

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp